# Changing the IP of a vSphere guest VM using Ansible

Tags: centos, centos6, vmware-vsphere, ansible

I want to deploy a VM from a template on vSphere and change the new instance IP via Ansible (2.x).
I've managed to clone the template with `vsphere_guest` module but I didn't find a way to change the IP of the new instance.
The new instance doesn't have an IP set from the start.
The final goal is to read static IP's from a config file and generate `n` new VM's each with an IP from the config file.
* VMware tools installed on the guest (CentOS 6.7)

Is this something that can be achieved using Ansible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a few different python/ansible scripts to achieve what you like:

- Deploy your VM from a template
- Get corresponding IP based on the VM name
- Change IP by tuning CentOS network configuration files

You can have a look on this [repo](https://github.com/mrlesmithjr/Ansible/tree/master/vsphere_playbooks) [github]. And [this one](https://github.com/mrlesmithjr/Ansible/tree/master/vm_provisioning) for the IP change part.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the IP address via the `networks` parameter of the [community.vmware.vmware_guest](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html) module. Just be aware, that setting the IP address will only work during deployment of the VM. If the VM does already exist, the IP address information will not be modified.

Example:

```
- name: Deploy VM
  community.vmware.vmware_guest:
    ...
    networks:
      - name: VM Network
        ip: 192.168.1.100
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        gateway: 192.168.1.1
```